# JSON formatted list view does not display a calculated column value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, calculated-column, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am using JSON view formatting to display list items in tiles. I use a calculated column to display a date in the "23 March 2021" format and output it as a single line of text.

However, even though the preview shows this text properly, when I added list web part to the homepage it is missing from there.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is it working properly in list itself (at URL: `<siteUrl>/lists/listName/viewName.aspx`)?

Comment: With <siteUrl>/lists/listName/viewName.aspx it does not work either, but it works with <siteUrl>/lists/listName/viewName.aspx?viewid=747f2958-bbd3-4750-a21...

Comment: Clear browser caches or change a browser to have a try?

Comment: Nope, it's not a browser thing. As said before /viewname.aspx doesn't work, /viewname.aspx?viewid=747f2958-... works. The webpart is using the 'clean' viewname.aspx so it doesn't work. :(

Comment: When I add the view picker to the webpart, and switch to All Items and back to my view the field appears.

Comment: Is the calculated column part of the view? It must be to be able to get its' value in formatting. If it was in the view then removed, or the value was loaded temporarily as part of clicking an item the value may display but won't on refresh. Alternatively, you could format a date column directly in formatting (skip the calculated column).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the column was not part of that view. Dumb me.

Thanks for all the answers and your help, everyone. :)